# What does stringWithUTF8String do?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring

So I have done some searching around so that I could see what it was I was doing with my code, and I couldn't find any answers as to what this very one specific line of code does.

```
NSString* name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:countryName];
```

I know what the rest does (I only had to google how to do this part), it is supposed to take my char* (countryName) and turn it into an NSString so later on I can compare it with the

```
isEqualToString:
```

thing. I would just like to know what the following is actually doing to the char, and what does the UTF8String even mean?

I have barely any Objective C programming experience so any feedback is helpful :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not totally right.
this method

> Returns a string created by copying the data from a given C array of UTF8-encoded bytes.

so, [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) string here is just a C array of bytes.

Check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Comment: Oh thank you so much!!!! I couldnt find that anywhere! and yeah the UTF8 thing made sense when I saw that it was related to Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do anything to the `char *` string.  It's just the input to the method.  `stringWithUTF8String` takes a C-style string (in [UTF-8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)), and creates an `NSString` using it as a template.